# The meaning of this syntax in Phaser framework

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm currently learning Phaser and get confused about some very basic concepts.
Such as, there often appears some syntax like these

```
this.fruit = this.game.add.group();
```

or

```
this.leftArrow = this.game.add.sprite();
```

I can understand the program is going to create a sprite or sprite group here.

So, 'fruit' and 'leftArrow' here are variable names? or something else?

When I tried this

```
var fruit;
fruit =  this.game.add.group();
```

It's wrong. What's the difference of these two code blocks? Is this a certain usage in Phaser?
(I'm sorry for asking such a newbie question, I think I missed some important basic concepts but I don't know what is it. I can't appreciate more if anyone answers my question. Thanks a lot!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two blocks are setting a field of the current object represented by "this". The second sets a local variable. If they are run in the context of an object the first block will modify that objects state while the second will not.

For example

```js
var obj = {
  name: 'Billy',
  changeName: function () {
    this.name = 'Sam';
  },
  brokenChangeName: function () {
    var name = 'Tim';
  }
}

console.log(obj.name); // Billy
obj.brokenChangeName();
console.log(obj.name); // Billy (nothing changed)
obj.changeName();
console.log(obj.name); // Sam   (changed)
```

Presumably your second version isn't working because in whatever context its running it is expected to modify the state of the object it belongs to, but instead it merely set a local variable which had its value discarded at the end of the function.

Comment: thank you so much... I think I understand what you meant, a difference between revising the object state and just a local variable... I misunderstood the concepts...